# Target error when using RCP + P2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2, tycho

Following the guides, I defined a target including both RCP and P2 features:

```xml
<?pde version="3.6"?>
<target name="MyTarget" sequenceNumber="1">
  <locations>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
      <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
      <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/"/>
    </location>
  </locations>
  <targetJRE path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
</target>
```

However, when I open this target with Eclipse, I have a conflict in org.eclipse.equinox.preferences between versions 3.4.0.v20110502 and 3.4.1.R37x_20110725... (see http://postimage.org/image/2zgruqrwk/ for a screenshot of the error).

Instead, tycho is able to correctly build the system... and this puzzles me even more!

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to force eclipse to use the latest version of P2 (which was marked "R37").

I cannot understand why eclipse would not use that version (instead tycho was using the correct version).